# javascript - using for (key in json) - I would like to get every other key note json consists only of objects

Tags: javascript, json, for-loop, object

I would like to use `for (key in json)` but only use every other key. It would be simple using arrays, but the json I recieve consists only of objects.

I have already asked a smililair question and th nicee people pointed out a typo and why it didn't work. The problem (I am still having) is that the content is duplicated (ie: I would like the 1st object in id="1" and the 2cnd object in id="2", then the 3rd object again in id="1" and the 4th object again in id="2" etc.)

The problem is that I get the 1st object in id="1" and id="2", then the 2cnd object again in id="1" and id="2".

For example lets say I have this json file:

```
"123":{
   "name":"someName",
   "age":"12",
   "health":{
      "heart":"OK",
      "lungs":"Not so good"
    }
},
"223":{
   "name":"someName1",
   "age":"42",
   "health":{
      "heart":"Not so good",
      "lungs":"OK"
    }
}
```

I would like to get name and lungs of the 1st patient into div id="1" and the 2cnd persons name and lungs into div id="2".

```
What I would like:
id="1" ... SomeName, OK
id="1" ... SomeName1, Not so good

What I actually get is:
id="1" ... SomeName, OK, SomeName1, Not so good
id="2" ... SomeName, OK, SomeName1, Not so good
```

so the question is how do I get every **other** `key` from the `for (key in json)` function.

Here is my code. Sorry for the long text, just wanted to make things clear. If you have any additional questions, let me know. Thanks.

```
    var data1 = document.getElementById("data1");
    var data2 = document.getElementById("data2");
    loadJSON(function(json) {
      var l = Object.keys(json).length;
      console.log("json start");
      for (var i = 0; i <= l; i++){
        console.log(i);
        if (i % 2 === 0){
          for (x in json) {
            data1.innerHTML+="<img src=" + json[x].picture + "/>";
            data1.innerHTML+=json[x].price_wrapper.price + json[x].price_thingy.suf + " modulo 0 + " + i;
            console.log("0" + i);
          }
        } else {
          for (x in json) {
            data2.innerHTML+="<img src=" + json[x].picture + "/>";
            data2.innerHTML+=json[x].price_wrapper.price + json[x].price_thingy.suf + " modulo 1 + " + i;
            console.log("1" + i);
          }
        } 
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

The credit goes to @Ashwin.

He reworked the code a little bit and now it works.

```
loadJSON(function(json) {
  console.log("json start");
  var i = 0;
  var l = Object.keys(json).length;
  for (x in json){
    console.log(i);
    if (i % 2 === 0){
      data1.innerHTML+="<img src=" + json[x].picture + "/>";
      data1.innerHTML+=json[x].price_thingy.price + json[x].price_thingy.suf;
      console.log("0 " + l);
    } else {
      data2.innerHTML+="<img src=" + json[x].picture + "/>";
      data2.innerHTML+=json[x].price_thingy.price + json[x].price_thingy.suf;
      console.log("1 " + l);
    }
    i++;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looping throught the entire json again. If I understand right you want only values of the json object with key l[i].

```
let json = 
  {
    "123":{
      "name":"someName",
      "age":"12",
      "health":{
        "heart":"OK",
        "lungs":"Not so good"
      }
    },
    "223": {
      "name":"someName1",
      "age":"42",
      "health":{
        "heart":"Not so good",
        "lungs":"OK"
      }
    }
  }

let l = Object.keys(json)
console.log(l.length)

for(let i = 0; i < l.length; i++){
  let element = json[l[i]];
  console.log(`id=${i}, ${element.name}, ${element.health.lungs}`);
}
```

Here is my example :

https://jsbin.com/yavosiroxi/edit?js,console